# How do I get the radio button value in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

I tried this but colors is unknown (I searched all over internet amazingly not one single person has documented it !):

```
V: view layout [
    across
    label "Colours:"
    r: radio of 'colours l: label "Red" 
    radio of 'colours label "Green" 
    radio of 'colours label "Blue"
    return
    label "Fruits:"
    radio of 'fruits label "Apples"
    radio of 'fruits label "Oranges"
    button "close" [unview]
]

probe colors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe radio buttons were designed that you named and checked each button:

```
mycolours: view layout [
    red: radio of 'colours label "Red"
    green: radio of 'colours label "Green"
    blue: radio of 'colours label "Blue"
]

probe red/data
probe green/data
probe blue/data
```

To get the answer from the word 'colours, you will have to iterate through faces to find faces with that relationship.  Here's a quick and dirty iterator ([walk-vid](http://reb4.me/r/walk-vid)):

```
walk-vid: use [level] [
    level: 0

    func [
        [catch]
        face [object!]
        callback [function!]
        /deep
    ][
        if not in face 'pane [
            throw make error! "Not a face"
        ]

        either deep [
            level: level + 1
        ][
            level: 0 bind second :callback 'level
        ]

        do [callback face]

        case [
            block? face/pane [
                foreach pane face/pane [
                    walk-vid/deep pane :callback
                ]
            ]

            object? face/pane [
                walk-vid/deep face/pane :callback
            ]
        ]

        either deep [
            level: level - 1
        ][
            level: 0
        ]

        face
    ]
]
```

So, iterate through faces, find relationship, find the selected face.  Let's make a function for that:

```
which-radio: func [
    face [object!]
    group [word!]
    /local selected
][
    walk-vid face func [face] [
        all [
            face/related == group
            face/data
            selected: face
        ]
    ]

    selected
]
```

Thus to wrap up:

```
probe which-radio mycolours 'colours
```

To make life easier, you can add a face/text value to the radio button (labels are not bound to the button):

```
radio of 'colours "Red" label "Red"
```

Comment: oh my I can't believe it has to be so complicated: why on earth can't colors just return [false true false] for example :)

Comment: Finally it's ok it may even be convenient http://askcodegeneration.com/jquery/ :)

Comment: I don't know why it's such a pain, or that a similar solution isn't baked into VID.  I wonder if it was a reluctance to assign this value to the global word `'colours` without a specific set-word notation.

Comment: On your code, you could shorten using case in place of multiple ifs: `case [local-file/data [...] jQuery-CDN/data [...] ...]`

Answer (score 0):

VID dialect does not provide such feature out of the box, but it is easy to add.

```
REBOL []

stylize/master [
    radio: radio with [
        get-all: has [list][
            if related [
                list: make block! 3
                foreach item parent-face/pane [
                    all [
                        item/related
                        item/related = related
                        append list to-logic item/data
                    ]
                ]
                list
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

view layout [
    across
    label "Colours:"
    r: radio of 'colours l: label "Red" 
    radio of 'colours label "Green" 
    radio of 'colours label "Blue"
    return
    label "Fruits:"
    f: radio of 'fruits label "Apples"
    radio of 'fruits label "Oranges"
    button "close" [unview]
]

print ["colours:" mold r/get-all]
print ["fruits:" mold f/get-all]
```

Supposing you want to alter all radio button styles, else you would need to remove */master* refinement.

Answer (score 0):

In R3GUI radio buttons are grouped by proximity, and you can get their values by naming each button.

```
view [ 
   r1: radio "one"
   r2: radio "two"
   r3: radio "three"
   button "show" on-action [ print get-face reduce [ r1 r2 r3 ]]
]
```